# Hows does java allow a name like Map.Entry? I thought a dot is not allowed

Tags: java, hashmap

How is the dot allowed in this interface name, I cannot create another class/interface name with a dot in the name.

Comment: Because it´s an inner interface of the `Map` `interface` which you are accessing.

Comment: A link for reference purposes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html. There is a discussion on it here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: @KevinEsche Actually it's an interface ;)

Comment: @vikingsteve yeah, corrected it for the correctness ;)

Comment: Ah, this was a stupid question...happens :)

Answer (score 5):

It's because `Entry` is a nested interface within the `Map` interface. You can create something similar if you want:

```
class MyClass {
  static class Nested { }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass.Nested n = new MyClass.Nested();
  }
}
```

Or to answer your question more directly:

```
class MyClass {
  static class MyEntry implements Map.Entry { }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map.Entry n = new MyEntry();
  }
  interface Map {
    interface Entry {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin Esche commented, when creating an inner class, it's fully qualified name would become `foo.bar.Outer.Inner`.

Answer (score 1):

The Entry interface is declared in the Map interface. It's an inner interface. So in order to use it, we have to make a reference to Map class, hence the Map.Entry.

Comment: Of course it's a public interface, otherwise you couldn't refer to it from another class. All members of an interface are automatically `public`, and `Map` is an interface, and `Entry` is a member of the interface `Map` so it's `public` too.